# Squares like stairs

Tags: turtle-graphics, smallbasic

Hello I want a sample program about this pattern using Small Basic which you need to use Turtle here. Thanks [Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyyBd.png)

so I was doing this as a sample which it is going to print "*" and I would like the asterisks to be replaced as square shape using turtle. here is the code:

```
For row = 1 To 10

    For column = 1 To row
       TextWindow.Write("*")
    EndFor

TextWindow.WriteLine("")
EndFor
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: That's my question like i want the output to be squares instead of asterisk but using Turtle graphics in small basic

Comment: That's a bit broad--could you make an attempt at solving it, then ask a technical question when you run into trouble? Thanks.

Comment: I shared the output that is attached to my concern. Then I programmed it to Small Basic. The thing is I want to use turtle graphics.

Comment: Small basic Turtle graphics

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. Although, it's still a bit broad and off-topic. Can you try drawing a square in small basic turtle graphics?

Answer (score 0):

I used [Small Visual Basic](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ModernVBNET.sVBInstaller) to create the exact shape you are asking for. Small Visual Basic is built on top of Small Basic and has many improvements and additions.

This is how the result will be:
[image]

and this is the code:

```
N = 10
Turtle.Speed = 50
GraphicsWindow.BrushColor = Colors.Green
While N > 0
   Turtle.X = 50 * (11 - N)
   Turtle.Y = 600
   For Row = 1 To N
      Turtle.CreateFigure()
      For I = 1 To 4
         Turtle.Move(50)
         Turtle.TurnRight()
      Next
      Turtle.FillFigure()
      Turtle.Move(50)
   Next
   N = N - 1       
Wend
```